# Why do I lose XM without doing any action?

Tags: ingress

It happened to me more than once, that my XM reserve would drop without any obvious reason.

E.g my XM reserve is at 100%, I'm travelling, not making any actions (hacking, firing, recharging, etc.), and next time I check it's down to 80% or even lower.

Is there anything that makes players lose XM over time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to aynchronousness of XM recharge.

### Technically speaking

When you collect XM, scanner shows an animation while calls the Ingress server to credit with the XM you collected. The animation goes, but the scanner doesn't yet know how much real XM you collected. After server returns data, the correct XM amount is displayed.

### Practically speaking

I have recently discovered that XM cannot be "multiplied" by having multiple players stand in the same place and collect the very same amount of XM before it disappears. I've been farming with another player and either one of us could gather XM. Since both our scanners displayed XM before we collected it at the same time, each scanner showed animation.

But server granted XM to only one of us, so the other saw XM bar dropping.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen my XM meter bar being incorrect at times. When I gain XM (usually using a power cube) it goes up twice the amount it should, then I stop picking up XM from my area because I'm full.

The first time after this when I'm using XM it corrects itself, and a simple recharge can take 2-3 times the 1000XM it should.

Comment: I have experienced this Issues so many times myself. I usually pop Power Cubes and the recharge to farm AP, and my bar will go full, even the narrator will say it is on 100%, but as soon as I recharge again, it drops to where it should actually have been in the first place.